# Formating jQuery UI DateRangePicker value (PHP)

Tags: php, date-formatting

I am using jQuery date range picker (http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/) when I submit data its showing below format.

```
 {"start":"2015-09-17","end":"2015-09-23"}
```

Now, I want to pick date only like this

```
<?php
$startDate: 2015-09-17;
$endDate: 2015-09-23;
?>
```

I used php **str_replace** but its not work properly.

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: That's just json. Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to to get an array or object back form which you can get those values. This is basic stuff.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a JSON string to a PHP array, you can use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Here's what your code might look like:

```
$jsonString = '{"start":"2015-09-17","end":"2015-09-23"}';
$array = json_decode($jsonString,true);

$startDate: $array['start'];
$endDate: $array['end'];
```

The second parameter of `json_decode` is `true`, which means the result will be an associative array (rather than an `object`).

Answer (score 0):

this is the json format, use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in php